# Make column value of table the result of 3 strings concatenated together MS Access 2013

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

One of my columns called "code" should store the result of concatenating 3 strings together. These 3 strings will be retrieved from the same table, but from 3 different columns. How can I do this in VBA? Or is there an easier way to do it in access?

I want this to be autocalculated once the user finishes entering the data in a form or table. I know it can be done in a query pretty easily but I'm finding it difficult to do in a table.

Comment: Calculated columns in a table are generally bad ideas. What is the ise case for the calculated column?

Comment: I have a Job Link Code which is composed of the Job#, Customer PO#, and Cust PO Line#, in the form of 000-000-000.

Comment: What I was getting at is those columns are already stored in the table. Producing the Job Link Code via Query or on the Form itself is trivial.

Comment: What @random_answer_guy wrote. Wherever you want to use this computed column, base that on a query (which has the computed column) instead of the original table.

Comment: And please read http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html : *The best answer is, "Don't!" ... You are violating fundamental rules of data normalization for no good purpose. We recommend you use queries for calculated fields, just as in previous versions.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a default value in the table https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Examples-of-expressions-d3901e11-c04e-4649-b40b-8b6ec5aed41f

Answer (score 0):

Seem the concatenation operator is &  so ...

```
 select column1 & column2 & colum3 from my_table
```

Comment: I knew about the & operator, but I don't know where I can use that code so that on every new entry it will autofill that field for me.

Comment: when  you do the Insert  .. could be the right place .. or the update .. iif happen ....anyway  .. if you have the column .. with a select  you have a result .. so is not mandatory  perform th concat in insert

Comment: Use a default value in the table https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Examples-of-expressions-d3901e11-c04e-4649-b40b-8b6ec5aed41f

Answer (score 0):

If You want to do this in a table:

In table designer, Computed Column Specification just write colA + colB + colC. But it all depends if there can be NULLS in columns, columns datatypes and many more.